# Trying to get property 'name' of non-object when trying to click next page using pagination

Tags: html, laravel

I get an error saying "Trying to get property 'name' of non-object" when I tried to click on next page using pagination.

Here is my Controller:

```
$websites = Website::all();
    $menu = Menu::with('categories')->whereHas('categories', function ($query) {
        $query->where('slug', request()->category);
    })->paginate(8);

    $categories = Category::all();
    $categoryName = $categories->where('slug', request()->category)->first()->name;

    return view('shopmenu')->with([
        'menu' => $menu,
        'categories' => $categories,
        'categoryName' => $categoryName,
        'websites' => $websites,
    ]);
```

The error is in this code:

```
 $categoryName = $categories->where('slug', request()->category)->first()->name;
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put check if you are getting any record then try to access `name`.

```
 $categoryName = $categories->where('slug', request()->category)->first();

 if ($categoryName) {
 $categoryName = $categoryName->name;
 }
```

Basically due to chaining when you get `null` in this query `$categories->where('slug', request()->category)->first()` and you try to access `name` property on `null` you get this error.

Comment: @AufaTafjyra Welcome, Accept and Approve.